# How to make a formControl emit only when its value is updated programmatically?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a formControl that I need to only emit when its value is updated programmatically. The control must always be enabled. A simplification of my real scenario is the following

In the component class

```
name = new FormControl();

onClick(value: string) {
  this.name.setValue(value);
}
```

In the component template

```
<div>
    <button type="button" (click)="onUpdateName('abc')">Update</button>
    <button type="button" (click)="onUpdateName('xml')">Update</button>
    <button type="button" (click)="onUpdateName('xyz')">Update</button>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="name">Name: </label>
    <input id="name" type="text" [formControl]="name" />
    <p>Value: {{ name.value }}</p>
</div>
```

The reason the control is always enabled is because in the real case this control is also used to filter values that update a list

An idea comes in handy. thanks for the feedback

Comment: Not sure if this would help, but you could add a hidden form element to update programmatically and keep the original one that the end-user can update. The form elements don't care how they're updated, just that the value has changed.

Comment: hello. Sorry to answer so late. Your idea helped me. It is implemented the way you have suggested. Thank you

Comment: Glad it worked, happy to help